# Refresh dynamically loaded async component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've a component where an async component depending on a property is loaded:

```js
const someProp = ref('');
const asyncComp = computed(() => defineAsyncComponent(
    () => import(`./../${someProp.value}Form.vue`));
```

But changing the component, the async component doesn't get refreshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to the reactivity system not detecting the change in the `someProp` value. To ensure that the `async` component gets refreshed when `someProp` changes, you need to make sure that it is properly reactive.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="changeComponent">Change Component</button>
    <component :is="asyncComp" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed, defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const someProp = ref('');
    const asyncComp = computed(() => defineAsyncComponent(
        () => import(`./../${someProp.value}Form.vue`)
    ));

    const changeComponent = () => {
      // Change the value of someProp to trigger the async component refresh
      someProp.value = 'NewComponent'; 
    };

    return {
      someProp,
      asyncComp,
      changeComponent
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

There are other ways to achieve dynamic component loading without relying on a computed property. One alternative approach is to use a `watcher` to react to changes in the `someProp` value and dynamically load the component. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { ref, defineAsyncComponent, watch } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const someProp = ref('');
    const asyncComp = ref(defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`./../${someProp.value}Form.vue`)));

    // Watch for changes in someProp and update asyncComp accordingly
    watch(someProp, (newValue, oldValue) => {
     asyncComp.value = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`./../${newValue}Form.vue`));
     });

    const changeComponent = () => {
      // Change the value of someProp to trigger the async component refresh
      someProp.value = 'NewComponent'; 
    };

    return {
      someProp,
      asyncComp,
      changeComponent
    };
  }
};
```

**--To check if an async component exists**

```
import { ref, defineAsyncComponent, watch } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const someProp = ref('');
    const asyncComp = ref(null); // Initialize with null

    // Watch for changes in someProp and update asyncComp accordingly
    watch(someProp, async (newValue, oldValue) => {
      try {
        // Attempt to import the async component
        const component = await import(`./../${newValue}Form.vue`);
        asyncComp.value = defineAsyncComponent(() => component);
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error if the async component doesn't exist
        console.error(`Error loading async component: ${error}`);
        asyncComp.value = null; // Reset asyncComp to null
      }
    });

    const changeComponent = () => {
      // Change the value of someProp to trigger the async component refresh
      someProp.value = 'NewComponent'; 
    };

    return {
      someProp,
      asyncComp,
      changeComponent
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: `asyncComp =` - this won't update in a view. computed can be replaced with ref+watch combo

Comment: You're right, I edited it.

Comment: @MohesnMahmoudi Thank you for the great reply. Is it also possible to check if an async component exists?

Comment: @SNO Yes, I edited the post and gave you an example.

Comment: @MohesnMahmoudi unfortunately the part with ```defineAsyncComponent``` throws an error ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: loader().catch is not a function```: ```asyncComp.value  = await defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`./path/${newVal}CreateForm.vue`) )``` works